# Two questions about a definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

My teacher (AP Calculus BC) gave me this problem:

"Let R be the shaded region in the first quadrant enclosed by the graphs of $y =e^{-x^2}$, $y=1-\cos x$, and the y-axis."

Obviously, this calls for a definite integral, which I wrote like this:
$$\int_0^b \left(e^{-x^2}-1+\cos x \right)dx$$
I put $b$ as the upper limit, as I hadn't found out yet.

However, this is my first question (elementary, I know): How would I find $b$?

I set up my equation like this:
$$e^{-x^2}=1-\cos x$$
I don't really know how to go on from here. I tried multiplying both sides by $1+\cos x$ but this didn't help.

Later, I used a solver to find the numerical approximation to the above equation, which gave me the upper bound of $0.942$.

Now, this leads to my second question. I have a definite integral: $$\int_0^{0.942} \left(e^{-x^2}-1+\cos x\right) dx$$
How would I evaluate this?

My first instinct was to split the integral up. When I split the integral, I ended up with this:
$$\int_0^{0.942}e^{-x^2}dx - \int_0^{0.942}1dx + \int_0^{0.942}\cos xdx$$
The second and third terms are very simple and easy to integrate. However, the first term, $\int_0^{0.942}e^{-x^2}dx$ would have to be solved with the error function. I only know the error function because of Math.SE, but is there any other way to solve this? Using the error function, $\int_0^{0.942}e^{-x^2}dx$ can be simplified to $\frac {\sqrt \pi} 2 \text{erf}(x)|_0^{0.942}$. This is supposed to be an AP Calculus BC problem, however, so I'm not sure if $\text{erf(x)}$ is the only way to go.

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form for $b.$

Comment: I would be surprised if there were any way to improve on your solution in any meaningful way.

Comment: Just use the Taylor expansion of $e^{-x^2}$ around $x=0$. If you take  the terms up to $x^8$, for the first integral you will get $0.724575$ instead of the exact $0.724226$.

Comment: "This problem [is](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/apc/calculus_ab_00.pdf) the first free response question from the 2000 Calculus AB Advanced Placement exam, in the section that allows (and requires calculators) for questions like this. 

The other commenters are correct, there is no solution to this problem in terms of algebraic or trigonometric functions. 


" From [JJB user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/746291/jjb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use the error function, expand the integrand as a Taylor series around $x=0$. This would give
$$e^{-x^2}-1+\cos (x)=1-\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{13 x^4}{24}-\frac{121 x^6}{720}+O\left(x^8\right)$$

Integrate termwise and use the bounds. This would give for the definite integral a value of $0.588605$ instead of $0.590962$ (relative error of $0.4$%).